# Why Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, asmx

I am using this web service but returns error:

***Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set.***

```
 [WebMethod]
    public DataTable ApprovalCertificate(int ID)
    {
        try
        {
            DatabaseConnection DatabaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection(Constants.Databases.BPAConnection);

            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand("ReportApprovalCertificate", DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection());
            SqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyDetailsID", ID);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCom);
            sqlDA.Fill(dt);

            DatabaseConnection.CloseConnection();

            return dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
        finally
        {
            //ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }

    }
```

I tried a lot but doesn't work.

Comment: which line gives you the error

Comment: Well have you tried specifying a name in the `DataTable` constructor call? (You should remove that try/catch/finally block too, as it's not doing any good.)

Comment: Try giving name to datatable using tablename property..that will help.  data table can not be serialized until or unless it has a name.

Answer (score 4):

data table can not be serialized until or unless it has a name. To resolve this error, we need to provide a name to the data table using the TableName property.

try giving name to it then serialize :

```
     dt = GetData() //fill data
     dt.TableName = "MyDt"
```